# Expression tree works when manual input, but not coming from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

Night, fellow citizens!
I`ve been making a little program to build expressions, but it doesn't work coming from this class.
I've tested it with the object comparer, but it doesn't find any differences.

```
    public class ExpressionUtility<T>
    {
        public ParameterExpression GetLambdaParam()
        {
            return Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        }

        public MemberExpression GetProperty(string propertyName)
        {
            return Expression.Property(GetLambdaParam(), propertyName);
        }

        public ConstantExpression GetConstant(object value, Type type)
        {
            return Expression.Constant(value, type);
        }

        public BinaryExpression BuildBinaryExpression(ExpressionObject expressionObj)
        {
            if (expressionObj.ExpressionType == ExpressionType.Equal)
                return Expression.Equal(GetProperty(expressionObj.PropertyName), GetConstant(expressionObj.Value, expressionObj.ObjectType));
            if (expressionObj.ExpressionType == ExpressionType.GreaterThan)
                return Expression.GreaterThan(GetProperty(expressionObj.PropertyName), GetConstant(expressionObj.Value, expressionObj.ObjectType));
            if (expressionObj.ExpressionType == ExpressionType.LessThan)
                return Expression.LessThan(GetProperty(expressionObj.PropertyName), GetConstant(expressionObj.Value, expressionObj.ObjectType));
            if (expressionObj.ExpressionType == ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual)
                return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(GetProperty(expressionObj.PropertyName), GetConstant(expressionObj.Value, expressionObj.ObjectType));
            if (expressionObj.ExpressionType == ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual)
                return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(GetProperty(expressionObj.PropertyName), GetConstant(expressionObj.Value, expressionObj.ObjectType));
            else
                throw new Exception("Binary Expression could not be formed!");
        }

        public Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildExpression(BinaryExpression expression)
        {
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, GetLambdaParam());
        }
    }
```

but it works here.

```
            var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Company), "p");
            var finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Company, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(param, "TradeName"),
                                                                         Expression.Constant("Matt's SoftwareHouse")), param);
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" never a good quote to find in a question. Always include the actual error. `GetLambdaParam()` don't generate new instances, it's not enough to have the same name, it has to be the same object.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the same ParameterExpression in the body as in the one you pass in when creating the Lambda. Compare this:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Constant(1),
        Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x")
    ),
    Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x")
)
```

To this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Constant(1),
        parameter
    ),
    parameter
)
```

They look almost identical, but the first example is invalid. The parameter that you access within the lambda's body needs to be the same parameter that is passed in to the `Expression.Lambda` method.